# Deploying SendGrid account using ARM template

Tags: sendgrid, azure-rm-template

I have an ARM template that deploys the SendGrid account but the deployment is always failing with error code": "ResourcePurchaseValidationFailed",
    "message": "User failed validation to purchase resources. Error message: 'Offer with PublisherId: Sendgrid, OfferId: sendgrid_azure cannot be purchased due to validation errors. See details for more information.'"

For the first time I was able to create the send grid account through portal successfully. Then for testing purpose I deleted that send grid account directly on portal and tried depoying through ARM template. Then onwards the deployment is failing with the above error when I try using both ARM template and Portal.

Please someone help me on this.

Comment: why dont you dig out the real error and show us?

Comment: "code": "DeploymentFailed",
  "message": "At least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-debug for usage details.",
  "details": [
    {
      "code": "BadRequest",
      "message": "{\r\n  \"error\": {\r\n    \"code\": \"ResourcePurchaseValidationFailed\",\r\n    \"message\": \"User failed validation to purchase resources. Error message: 'Offer with PublisherId: Sendgrid, OfferId: sendgrid_azure cannot be purchased due to validation errors. See details for more information.'\"\r\n  }\r\n}"
    }
  ]

Comment: this is the only error detail at get at operation level.

Comment: well, check resource group actions for real error? or correlation log?

Comment: Nowhere I can find the details on this error. I checked activity log also for the resource group I did deployment

Comment: I'm also getting this error, but creating one for the first time. Perhaps their user verification endpoint is currently unhealthy?

Comment: Seems the issue got fixed. As Dan mentioned it was some problem at sendgrid end and today it started working again.